# Properly Send AJAX Post for Stripe in React.js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am writing a react app utilising stripe payments, and am using Stripe react elements for my payment form. I am client-side rendering and using php for the backend.

The issue I'm having is with properly sending the stripe token to my server. I have gotten it working using a plain http request but I don't want to link to my action so AJAX it is.

I'm currently using jQuery and am getting the error, "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." I've read on this and understand that CORS is the solution but beyond this I don't think adding the whole jQuery library is the "correct" way to this for react stripe elements.

What is the proper way to do this when utilising this framework? My code is as follows:

My booking page:

```
//other imports are here also
import BookingForm from '../components/bookingform/BookingForm';
//Stripe provider is imported at index.js level


class BookingPage extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super(); 
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <div>

    <StripeProvider apiKey="my_api_key">
      <BookingForm />
    </StripeProvider>

  </div>
);


}
}

export default BookingPage;
```

My Booking Form:

```
import React from 'react';
import {injectStripe} from 'react-stripe-elements';
import CardSection from './components/CardSection';
import $ from "jquery";


class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        firstName: '', 
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phoneNumber: '',
        numberOfPassengers: '',
        pgerUnderSevenSelected: 'no',
        specialRequests: '',
        isOneWay: 'yes',
        transferFrom: '',
        transferTo: '',
        date: '',
        time: '',

    }
}

change = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
    });
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

this.props.stripe.createToken({name: 'Jenny Rosen'}).then(({token}) => {
  console.log('Received Stripe token:', token);
  if (token===undefined) {
    console.log('Token Error');
  } else {

    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
          const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
          const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);

          console.log(hiddenInput);

          form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

          //HERE IS THE JQUERY I WOULD LIKE TO REPLACE
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'http://localhost//my-server.php',
              data: $('form').serialize(),
              success: function () {
                  alert('form was submitted');
              },
                  error: function(data,textStatus) {
                  console.log("Ajax Error!");
              }
           });
       }
   });
};

render () {
    return (
        <div className="container form-container check-it">
            <form 
                action="http://localhost//my-server.php" 
                method="post" 
                id="payment-form" 
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <div className="row">
                    <div className='col-12'>
                        <CardSection />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Book Now" />
                </div>
             </form>
         </div>
    );
}
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

I'm using XAMP for my local php server.

A final note: I'm a beginner as far as back end stuff goes so even direction to relevant documentation to read through regarding AJAX would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL of the page where the form is shown?

Comment: At the moment it's on local host. I'm using react-router-dom so it's localhost:3000/booking-page

Comment: I think you might be getting the access control issue due to the difference in port number here (you're serving on `localhost:3000` but posting to `localhost.` Using jquery here is perfectly fine. If you'd prefer to make your ajax request in vanilla javascript that's easily doable as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks duck, yes I added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); to my dev build, my main question was whether importing all of jQuery is overkill in this instance. I know if too many libraries are imported page load time becomes an issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also for the record it's all going to be hosted at the same address so I'll remove the header when doing the final build.